# Jquery - Adding and removing stylesheet on click

Tags: jquery, css, append

I've got an element set to append a style-sheet into the head via the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".css_switch").click(function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />');
    });
});
```

It's working as required in terms of adding the style-sheet to the head and giving the required effect, however what I would like is that when you click `.css_switch`, it removes the style-sheet that I just added to the head, so it sort of turns it off and on.

Please note I don't want to disable the original style-sheet at all, as I am still using a large chunk of that.

Thanks.

Comment: When you append stylesheet also add an ID, so you can easily remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove a stylesheet completely from DOM: just *disable* it. It's easy to do, actually, but there are two things to be aware of:

```
$(function() {
  var linkEl;
  $(".css_switch").click(function() {
    if (!linkEl) {
      linkEl = $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />')
                .appendTo('head')[0];
    }
    else if (linkEl.sheet) {
      linkEl.sheet.disabled = !linkEl.sheet.disabled;
    }
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o46pfgyk/). Each style [link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement) has associated [StyleSheet object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet), which can be disabled with, quite unsurprisingly, [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) property. But there's a caveat: the aforementioned object is created only when the external CSS document is loaded and parsed. Until this, `linkEl.sheet` is `null`; hence the check.

Note that simpler version:

```
else { linkEl.disabled = !linkEl.disabled; }
```

... works too (you change property of corresponding `HTMLLinkElement`, disabling it instead), but there's a subtle bug: this property can be changed **even when the resource is not ready**. So imagine a user clicking on the button, seeing no changes afterwards (CSS isn't loaded yet). Now they click the button again, this time disabling the link - and when the resource is there, it's not shown. A user is <strike>dazed and</strike> confused, and that's *usually not good*.

With the quoted version, disabling is done only when a user sees the result of CSS change.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.

Comment: Following up on this, How would I store this in a cookie so it applies to the entire site when clicking through etc?

Comment: Store 'what' in cookies? And why cookies anyway, when you can use localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```js
var addstyle = 'true';
$('.button').on("click", function addorremovesheet() {
  if (addstyle == true) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dark.css" type="text/css" />');
    var addstyle = 'false';
  } else {
    $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="styles/dark.css"]').remove();
    var addstyle = 'true';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<div class="button">click</div>
```

Is a bit shorter ;-)
If sth. is not working please write me...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practices to load CSS on the fly, instead, you should load it first and use ID or name to control what is enabled or disabled